# help for writing a rosinstall on rosdisto

Tags: ros, rosinstall, git, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I wrote four ros pkg's all are located in one git repo.

- Do I have to write four rosinstall files on rosdisto?
- How should I design the the rosinstall file because one cannot checkout a git sub-folder?

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52308/help-for-writing-a-rosinstall-on-rosdisto/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is common to have multiple packages in one git repo, and this would just be a single rosinstall entry in rosdistro. If you wanted to provide your packages separately from one another, you'd have to move them to separate repos (or use svn).

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1